# How can i create a new table from a value and the moving average of that value in an postgresql insert into statement?

Tags: postgresql

Let's say i have a table of the following form:

```
create table source (
m_id serial,
a_id integer,
value1 integer[],
value2 integer[],
primary key(m_id));
```

| m_id | a_id | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | `{1,2,...}` | `{5,3,...}` |
| 2 | 1 | `{6,4,...}` | `{2,4,...}` |
| 3 | 1 | `{1,6,...}` | `{8,7,...}` |

Here, `value1` and `value2` are arrays of length 20.
`a_id` is not unique and equal values define a subset of rows.
What i want to do is create a new table:

```
create table destination (
n_id serial,
value1 integer,
value2 integer,
avg_val1 numeric,
avg_val2 numeric,
primary key (n_id));
```

| n_id | value1 | value2 | avg_value1 | avg_value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | ... | ... |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |
| 4 |  |  |  |  |

where `destination.value1` and `destination.value2` are the unnested values of `source.value1` and `source.value2`,
`avg_val1` and `avg_val2` are the moving averages over `destination.value1` and `destination.value2`.

What i have tried so far is:

```
insert into destination (value1, value2, avg_value1, avg_value2)
select 
unnest(value1), 
unnest(value2), 
avg(unnest(value1)) over (rows between 5 preceding and current row), 
avg(unnest(value2)) over (rows between 5 preceding and current row)
from source where a_id = 1;
```

which gives me the following error:

> ERROR:  window function calls cannot contain set-returning function calls
>
> HINT:  You might be able to move the set-returning function into a LATERAL FROM item.
>
> SQL state: 0A000

a quick google search for the `LATERAL FROM` brings up [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-table-expressions.html) page. But i am not quite understanding how this would help here.

i've also tried it with an update statement

```
insert into destination (value1, value2) 
select unnest(value1), unnest(value2) from source where a_id = 1;
update destination 
set value1 = avg(value1) over (rows between 50 preceding and current row);
```

which just gives me the following error:

> ERROR:  window functions are not allowed in UPDATE
>
> SQL state: 42P20

So, how do i do this?
Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, found a possible way:

```
insert into destination (
    value1, 
    value2,
    avg_value1,
    avg_value2)
select 
    val1, 
    val2, 
    avg(val1) over (rows between 5 preceding and current row),
    avg(val2) over (rows between 5 preceding and current row)
from (
    select value1 as val1, value2 as val2 
    from source where a_id = 1) as tmp;
```